# MSIX install error : 0x80073cfd - A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied

Tags: appx, msix

I converted the notepad++ exe to an MSIX file using the tool. I wanted to install notepad++ on a windows 7 machine using the msix that I created.I installed MSIX core on my windows 7 machine.
 But I get the error "0x80073cfd - A Prerequisite for an install could not be satisfied." when I click the install button on the msix. I have installed the signed certificate on the machine under Trusted people in Local Machine. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be that you have specified the wrong target device family in the Package.appxmanifest in your Windows Application Packaging Project.

Please try this and specify the supported MSIX Core version for Windows 7 SP1 as following:

```
  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="MSIXCore.Desktop" MinVersion="6.1.7601.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.10240.0" />
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.16299.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.18362.0" />
  </Dependencies>
```

Reference:
[Update your existing MSIX package to support MSIX Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/msix-core/support-msix-core)